# SQL query to remove incorrect entries from a database with date column as decision criterion

Tags: sql, oracle

Due to incorrect insertions I have several wrong entries in a database. These occur in groups of four. Examples:

```
ID_A  Startdate     Enddate      ID_B
296   05.09.2013    28.10.2017   62
296   05.09.2013    01.01.2999   62
296   28.10.2017    05.09.2013   65
296   28.10.2017    01.01.2999   65

285   26.02.2016    07.09.2018   93
285   26.02.2016    01.01.2999   93
285   07.09.2018    26.02.2016   58
285   07.09.2018    01.01.2999   58
```

There can only be one valid entry for a given period. The second and third entries do not belong in the table and must be removed. The end date of the first entry must be the same as the start date of the next. I can easily identify the third entry because the end date is smaller than the start date.

```
Delete from table where ID_A = 296 and Enddate < Startdate
```

But for the second line I have no idea yet.  My desired result is to make two valid entries from the upper four lines:

```
ID_A  Startdate     Enddate      ID_B
296   05.09.2013    28.10.2017   62
296   28.10.2017    01.01.2999   65

285   26.02.2016    07.09.2018   93
285   07.09.2018    01.01.2999   58
```

Anybody got any ideas on how I should go about this?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Are you sure there are no other situations?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 1) Sorry about that. 2) There are only such situations where there is a mistake.

Comment: So, are the only "mistakes" in one of the following two classes? And if you delete all of those mistakes, what is left is correct? The two classes are: (1) ENDDATE is less than STARTDATE; (2) ENDDATE is 1 January 2999, but there are two or more rows for the same ID_A with this ENDDATE; of these rows, only the one with the greatest STARTDATE is correct, and all the others are "mistakes". Is that it?

Comment: @mathguy I want to definetly keep the entry with the smallest startdate having an enddate in the past. Additionally i want to keep the entry having that enddate as startdate and enddate in the future. From each group the first and last entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
delete from t
    where not exists (select 1
                      from t t2
                      where t2.startdate = t.enddate
                     ) and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.startdate < t.startdate or
                        (t2.startdate = t.startdate and t2.enddate < t.enddate)
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c37aa4a95238e70527d061a7b0d8f0e) is a db<>fiddle.

This works for your sample data.  It is checking that there is a "matching" record before a current record -- and that the current record is not the first.  It would not work for all incarnations.  In fact, you could have some complex interleaved records where a single solution is not obvious.

Comment: Your approach deletes the second entry as desired but also the fourth which I want to keep. Any idea how i can delete second and third entries and keep first and last?

Comment: @wannaBeDev . . . The earliest start date is duplicated.  I adjusted the logic and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I had to modify it to suit my needs. But you have led me in the right direction. Thanks for the link to db<>fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You may try below -

```
Delete from table t1
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t1.ID_A = t2.ID_A
              and t1.Startdate = t2.Startdate
              and t1.ID_B = t2.ID_B
              and t1.Enddate > t2.Enddate)
```

Comment: Your approach deletes the second entry as desired but also the fourth which I want to keep. Any idea how i can delete second and third entries and keep first and last?